# Selecting values in one array based on another

Tags: vba, excel

I've done some relatively straightforward things in VBA before but I think for this project I need to move into using variables and possibly arrays, which seem to be just beyond my reach at the moment.

I've got 4 columns of data: col. A is start times, col. B is the corresponding end times (there will be about 30 of each), col. C is time-stamps for the data points (collected during and between the time periods specified in columns A and B; there are 40,000+ lines of data in these columns), and col. D is the data observed at each time point referenced in col. C. Each file will have different start/end times, so I want to make a macro that can read them from the cells.

I need to put the time-stamp and data points from each time period specified in columns A and B, into separate columns (so, for example, time period 1 data will be in columns F and G, time period 2 data will be in H and I, and so on). So, I want to write a macro that will essentially search col. C for values that fall between the start and end times of the first time period, and copy/paste the relevant ones into the appropriate new columns.

I've been googling like crazy but I'm having a hard time putting together various pieces of code that can address the different steps. This is what I have so far (along with some notes saying what I *think* things are supposed to be doing):

```
Sub CopyRows2()

Dim endTime As Range, startTime As Range
Dim copyRange As Range, lastRow As Range, timePoint As Range
Dim i As Long, k As Long

    Set startTime = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  'find the last row of the time periods
    Set timePoint = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 3)  'start looking for times in cell C2
  Do Until lastRow = ""
    For i = 2 To lastRow
       Set endTime = startTime.Offset(0, 1)   'identify the end of the time period
            If timePoint.Value >= startTime.Value Then    'find the row with the first data point in the time period
                If copyRange Is Nothing Then   'this "copyRange" stuff is based on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790924/excel-vba-how-to-select-rows-based-on-data-in-a-column
                    Set copyRange = ActiveSheet.Rows(i)
                Else
                   Set copyRange = Union(copyRange, ActiveSheet.Rows(1))
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    If Not copyRange Is Nothing Then
        ActiveSheet.copyRange.Copy ActiveSheet.Cells(2, k)  'k is meant to be the column number, which will keep incrementing by 2 but I don't know how to tell it to do that
       End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Right now it's giving me an error:

> "Application-defined or object-defined error"

On this line:

```
Set startTime = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
```

And I can't figure out why. But, I'm pretty sure that there are larger problems with it and it probably won't actually do what I'm trying to get it to do, even if I fix the problem that's causing the error.

At the moment the specific things I hope someone might be able to help with are:

1. What is causing the error?
2. How do I define k so that it will increment by 2 (see the note in the code above)

But, I know that there might be a much better way to do this -- if so, other suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: What does column A look like? Are there blanks between the cells? Or is it all constant until time change?

Comment: Regarding point 2: `For k = 2 to lastRow Step 2`  -- the rest is a bit more complicated.  So the data in Column A & B are related, and C & D are related, and they're all thrown together on the same sheet for some reason?  edit -- can you also mark what line you're getting the error on?

Comment: Adding as a comment instead of an answer, this seems like a fair bit of work but it looks like you're off to a great start.  One problem I'm sure you'll run into is the huge run time for looking at 40k rows over and over.  I'd suggest 1.) Cut C & D and paste on a new sheet, 2.) Autofilter and sort both sheets using the built in Sort & Filter tools, 3.) Loop through the first sheet, pasting to a new destination sheet in new columns, and then have it search the sheet with C & D on it, having it terminate the loop when it exceeds that timespan for that range, and moving to the next range

Comment: @findwindow: Column A does not have any blanks, it's just one start time after another. Same with Column B.

Comment: @Acantud: It seemed simpler to put everything in the same sheet, rather than referring to other worksheets or workbooks. In my limited experience I thought this would make it easier -- is that not right? (reply to your second comment coming in a minute...)

Comment: @Acantud: The values in C are already in order -- I was hoping that the code above would basically just find the first value in the time period, and select down to the last one (not literally using "Select" but that's what I thought it would do conceptually). For your suggested Step 3: Do you mean that the values from A and B would be pasted into the new sheet? Or into the sheet that C and D were pasted into? Can you tell me why that would be better than the 4-column setup I've already got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumes data starts in row 2. Make sure Range D1 is not empty.

```
Sub CopyRows2()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

'clear enough columns for ~30 data sets
Columns("E:CA").ClearContents

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet2")
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
x = 2

With ws

    'fill columns A+B to correspond with C
    Do Until Cells(lastRow, 1) <> ""

        If .Cells(x, 2) <> .Cells(x, 3) Then
            .Range("A" & x + 1 & ":B" & x + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            .Cells(x + 1, 1) = .Cells(x, 1)
            .Cells(x + 1, 2) = .Cells(x, 2)
        End If

        x = x + 1

    Loop

    'move blocks
    i = 2
    c = 1


    Do Until i > lastRow

        'change in column A
        If .Cells(i + 1, 1) <> .Cells(i, 1) Then
            .Range("c" & i - c + 1 & ":D" & i).Copy
            lastCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            .Cells(1, lastCol + 1).PasteSpecial
            c = 0
        End If

        i = i + 1
        c = c + 1

    Loop

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It seems that this is transposing the C & D columns into a single row, rather than referring to the time period start/end times in columns A & B. I tried changing the "If" statement to:
`If .Cells(i + 1, 3) > .Cells(i, 1) And .Cells(i + 1, 2) < .Cells(i, 2) Then`
but it doesn't seem to be reading the values in A & B.

Comment: It's showing up in columns for me, not single row. Can you provide example for what before and after should look like?

Comment: Do you want to move the corresponding columns A and B as well? But yea, example is best.

Comment: The data in A and B doesn't need to be moved. Also I changed two references from your original solution (it won't let me change this in the code because it's too few characters, apparently):
'lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row'
and
'If .Cells(i +1, 3) <> .Cells(i, 1) Then'
Just so we're looking at the same thing :-)
[trying to figure out how to post an example...]

Comment: Hmm I think I am picturing the data incorrectly because all the columns should be same height and you're testing for a change in A not C?

Comment: Yes, the columns are different heights. In the real files, A and B will each have 30 rows, and C and D will have several thousand rows. I'm working with an example right now that just uses 3 rows in A & B, and about 20 in C & D.

Comment: Here's a link to a file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/59nauq8u5yuxlub/example.xlsx?dl=0

Columns A through D are the data that's in the file to begin with. The remaining columns show how I hope to get the data to end up -- sorted based on the values in A and B.

Comment: Oh -_- I pictured 8:00:00 in A from rows 3 to 7. This is much more difficult.

Comment: Think you can code something to shift A down to match C?

Comment: Hmm if it's always 5 min intervals, you can try dividing C by 5 to grab blocks?

Comment: I'm not sure...part of the problem with this particular dataset is that the number of rows in each time period won't always be the same. If I can make it search C for the value in A, then yes.

Comment: It will always be 5-minute intervals. I would still have to specify an end time, though, yes? Would it be easier to somehow add 5 minutes to the start time using code, rather than specifying the end time in a cell?

Comment: It gives an "Application-defined or object-defined error" message on the first "If...Then" line. When I run through it step-by-step it just skips from that line to the "End If" line as though it's not "seeing" that the values should be selected.

Comment: Oops...Now it works! The only thing it didn't like was the `Do Until` line (it seems to be getting stuck in that loop), so I set it to an x value that will exceed the number of lines that'll end up being in columns A&B. Thank you SO much!

Comment: Oh. I think I forgot a period XD