# Copy all Rows in excel sheet only if specific cell = today's date

Tags: vba, excel

I'm knew to vb scripting for excel and cant seem to find code that will help do what i want. maybe its how im wording my search criteria.

Sheet 1 is an input sheet which saves data into sheet 2 every day. There is a cell that holds the current date.

So sheet 2 just collates and saves everything entered.

Each day there are several rows saved into sheet 2.
I need a button on sheet two that only selects the rows that have today's date and copies the content. I just need that data copied so i can then paste this into off clipboard into another application.

Can anyone help? im using office 2016.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Anthony. I would suggest you record a macro, where you apply a filter to sheet 2; then filter for todays date; then copy all the rows; then stop the macro recorder and look at the recorded code. I think this will provide you with a good starting point.

Comment: I cant use the macro function as i cannot determine the numbers of rows there will be from one day to the next. and i need to use vb code to determine the number of rows that will need copying.

Answer (score 0):

[Excel VBA, How to select rows based on data in a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790924/excel-vba-how-to-select-rows-based-on-data-in-a-column)

I believe this is something that would be useful for yourself since you are new to VBA code.

You will most likely need to supplement your code with the parts you ned, IE current date, only coping and not pasting and so forth.

I recommend google for those parts as it is widely avalible, I.E. VBA Excel "then what you are searching for"

```
Dim TodaysDate As Date

TodaysDate = Now
TodaysDate = Format(TodaysDate, "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

^ For instance will give you the current day in dd/mm/yyyy format

I leave the rest to you, hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I would loop through the rows in the second sheet and hide the rows not matching the date. So something similar to this:

```
Dim today As String
Dim Rows As Integer
Dim Sheetname As String
Dim Column As Integer

Sheetname = "Sheet2" 'Name of your second sheet
Column = 1 'Column with your date

today = Now
today = Format(today, "dd/mm/yyyy")

Rows = Sheets(Sheetname).UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To Rows Step 1
    If Sheets(Sheetname).Cells(i, Column).Value <> today Then
        Sheets(Sheetname).Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next i
```

Then you can copy the rows of today.
To show all rows again, simply use

```
Dim Sheetname As String

Sheetname = "Sheet2" 'name of your second sheet

Sheets(Sheetname).Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
```