# Filter Table by Column. (Filter --> Filter Between--> Number Range) --> Output New Table

Tags: vba, excel, filter

I am trying to use VBA to filter a table by  column's values, and then have a new table (filtered) be output on worksheet, but a new area .Note I want to cell reference the range numbers.

On the fake excel table below. I want to filter for range for column 'age'. I.e. filter --> age --> between 1-3 (cell reference). First table is raw data. Second is what I would like as output using VBA.

I tried fitting the code below to my desired output. It is missing data not relevant to the column itself (taking full columns)

Image of raw data and desired output below
[image]

[Excel VBA, How to select rows based on data in a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790924/excel-vba-how-to-select-rows-based-on-data-in-a-column)

```
Option Explicit
Sub tablefilter()
    Dim lastRow As Long, x As Long
    Dim lasColumn As Long, i = 4 
    Dim CopyRange As Range

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For x = 1 To lastRow
            If Len(Trim(.Range("A" & x).Value)) 1<3 Then
                If CopyRange Is Nothing Then
                    Set CopyRange = .Rows(i)
                Else
                    Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, .Rows(x))
                End If
            End If
        Next
        If Not CopyRange Is Nothing Then
            CopyRange.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(1)
        End If
    End With
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here... Please refer to [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you'd like help with your code, we're more than willing to help you out, we do not however provide code

Comment: Line `If Len(Trim(.Range("A" & x).Value)) 1<3 Then` contains a syntax error. Are you looking for rows with text lengths smaller than 3? If so, try `If Len(Trim(.Range("A" & x).Value)) < 3 Then`.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. This is for a model with numbers, not text values. I think there is some inefficiency in the code, but it does work. Main issue is just it uses two sheets instead of creating a new table on same sheet. 
D2/D3 are cell reference numbers, and G is the column.

Sub MaturityRange()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Model As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output")
Set One = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Model")

If Not IsEmpty(One.Range("D2")) And Not IsEmpty(One.Range("D3")) Then
    With ws
        .Range("$G$7:$G$" & .Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).AutoFilter Field:=1, _
            Criteria1:=">" & One.Range("D2").Value, _
            Operator:=xlAnd, _
            Criteria2:="<" & One.Range("D3").Value
    End With
End If

End Sub